# Can I deploy a sqlite DB that already has data in a docker container?

Tags: docker, sqlite, docker-compose, fastapi, uvicorn

I searched and all the answers seem to be focused on having changes made to the db persist after the container has been brought down, but that's not what I'm after. I just want the docker to already contain a table with dome data (7-10 M rows)

I have an app in fastapi/uvicorn, It's very basic: It receives a series of parameters and fetches some data based on them from a local DB. it works correctly using mysql.

Now I want to be able to put everything in a docker container, fastpi/uvicorn is no issue. for the DB I'm using mysql but I'm thinking of switching to sqlite.

I only need to read the data, the process will never modify the tables, so I would like to deploy the container with all the data (DB, tables) already in there so I can just pull the container and have it running.

It's very important that I do not depend on any resource on the host or anything outside the container as basically this will be deployed as a black box using ECR in AWS. (the image will be served using either ec2 or fargate)

What is the preferred way to put everything in the same container?

any pointer in the right direction will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What happens if you try it?  Is there any particular issue you're running into?  (If the database is really truly read-only, you make sure to open it in read-only mode, and the SQLite data file isn't larger than hundreds of megabytes, mechanically this should work fine.)

Comment: @DavidMaze, the thing is, I managed to get the DB and server docker running.. but the data cannot be "baked-in", at least I don't find any clear way to do so. every time it starts it is empty again... the other thing is I tried using volumes but they are not committed since they live in the localhost so when I deploy it to a different machine the data is just not there.

do you happen to know somewhere I can read on how to achieve this "already there" data approach?